# image download by php curl or file_get_content

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, imagedownload

I am trying to download image from [`here`](http://s3.amazonaws.com/test_bucket/test_12_12_2013_10_51_00.jpg)

the above url by using both php curl and file_get_content. But when i am using php curl the image is downloaded but it have no content, when i am using `file_get_content` the following error occurs,

`Warning: file_get_contents(http://s3.amazonaws.com/test_bucket/test_12_12_2013_10_51_00.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported in /home/webdev/public_html/example/photos/download.php on line 11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the link you provided is not an image. It outputs..

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AllAccessDisabled</Code>
<Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message>
<RequestId>35DFBD44D75B45C4</RequestId>
<HostId>
n1TT+gOUuMJ3RydGND/s3QL73JJEadz/2uQutK4NNUDbEaGX6EI0Y8a/6eDHLR6H
</HostId>
</Error>
```

### Tested & Works !

Below code reads an image from an URL, saves it and then opens/renders on browser.

```
<?php
$image ="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png";
$ch = curl_init($image);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$fp = fopen("test.jpg",'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp);
header ("Content-Type: image/png");
readfile("test.jpg");
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

**Or**

If you want just to render it.. Do like this.

```
<?php
readfile("http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png");
header ("Content-Type: image/png");
```